# Increase idle timeout

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an App service in Azure: a php script that makes a migration from a database (server1) to a another database (azure db in a virtual machine).

This script makes a lot of queries and requests, so it takes a lot of time and the server (App service) returns:

> "500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within
>   the specified time."

I found that it's something about "idle timeout." I would like to know how to increase this time.

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I have tried the following so far:

- Add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` at the top of my PHP script.
- App settings on portal: `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 3600`.

But nothing seems to work.

After some searching, I found the [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17305ddc-07b2-436c-881b-286d1744c98f/503-errors-with-large-pdf-file?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) by David Ebbo, as he said:

> There is a 230 second (i.e. a little less than 4 mins) timeout for
>   requests that are not sending any data back. After that, the client
>   gets the 500 you saw, even though in reality the request is allowed to
>   continue server side.

And the similar thread from SO, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673318/azure-asp-net-webapp-the-request-timed-out).

The suggestion for migration is that you can leverage `Web Jobs` to run PHP scripts as background processes on App Service Web Apps.
For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs.