# majento 1.9.3 product upload error shows server response time error on azure

Tags: php, azure, magento-1.9

I am trying to upload products on majento admin by csv and it is showing the following error:

500 - The request timed out.

### 500 - The request timed out.

The web server failed to respond within the specified time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhnUy.png)

php.ani on azure server does not allow to change the server response time.Attached screenshot of the error. tried with users.ini file also.

any suggestions?

With regards,
Jitandra Singh

Answer (score 0):

According to your error capture, you attempted to modify the php configuration file in Azure runtime. As the customers, we do not have the permission to modify the files out of the `home` folder in Azure runtime.

If you want to change the PHP configurations on Azure Web App, you can create a configuration file like `.user.ini` in the root directory of your application, and set the configurations as same as in traditional `php.ini`. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations for more details.

Furthermore, according your image, it seems that you attempted to enlarge the execution time, in Azure Web Apps, there is an almost 230 seconds timeout restriction. you can refer to [Azure ASP .net WebApp The request timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673318/azure-asp-net-webapp-the-request-timed-out) .

If you require a long execution time in progress, you can leverage [Web Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs).