# asp.net MVC Web API unknown error long running task

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-web-api2

I am using angular 7 for front end and calling web api built using asp.net mvc deployed in Azure web app services.

For a specific API for uploading file, I get "Http failure response for {APIURL}: 0 Unknown Error" where 0 is response status. If the file is smaller than 400MB, this works fine. However for files larger than 400MB I get the above error on front end after 3-4 minutes. But at the backend, web API continues to run and completes in around 4-5 minutes total time.

I am using HttpClient requests from angular. Any pointer will be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to call the above API endpoint from Postman tool, I found that due CORS error I was getting response status 0 unknown error.

The actual error was '500 - The request timed out.'. This is due to the fact that azure web app times out after 230 seconds. I found a similar question on stack overflow at: [Azure ASP .net WebApp The request timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673318/azure-asp-net-webapp-the-request-timed-out)