# 500 - The request timed out || The web server failed to respond within the specified time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-post, azure-webapps, request-timed-out

I have hosted an ASP.NET **Web App** in Azure App service. The function of web app is to read the data from CSV file and while (csv.ReadNextRecord()) holds true, **mandatory** columns data are used to send user invitation using invitation endpoint[HTTP POST Method] and **optional** columns data are used to patch the data to the user, post **successful** invitation[HTTP PATCH Method]. The app runs good locally but when deployed it won't run past 3:59 mins. and throws an **Error** as shown below:

[image]

**Sample Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Post method for importing users 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="postedFile"></param>
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportAsync(IFormFile postedFile)
{
    if (postedFile != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                //Some Code Here...
            }

            //Validate uploaded file and return error.
            if (fileExtension != ".csv")
            {
                //Some Code Here...
            }
            //Copy the contents of uploaded file
            //with the same filename as uploaded file
            //under the "wwwroot/Uploads" directory
            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //Some Code Here...
            }
            // open the CSV file which is a CSV file with headers
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, true))
            {
                //Some Code Here...
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Some Code Here...
                }
                //Validation for mandatory columns
                if (!HeaderExists)
                {
                    //Some Code Here...
                }
                else
                {
                    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                    {
                        //Some Code Here...
                        #region Prepare user data with mandatory and optional attributes seperately
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            //Some Code Here...
                        }
                        #endregion

                        #region Invite User, Patch Optional User Data and Add User to Group
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InvitedUserEmailAddress))
                        {
                            bool isValidEmail = //Some Code Here...
                            if (isValidEmail)
                            {
                                //Some Code Here...
                                
                                var userInvitationStatus = //Some Code Here...
                                if (userInvitationStatus)
                                {
                                    //Some Code Here...
                                    #region Patch Optional User Data
                                    if (userDataToPatch.Count != 0)
                                    {
                                        //Some Code Here...
                                        var userPatchStatus = //Some Code Here...
                                        if (userPatchStatus)
                                        {
                                            //Some Code Here...
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //Some Code Here...
                                    }
                                    #endregion

                                    #region Add User to Group
                                    //Add user to group if there is some data provided in the optional groupObjectId column
                                    if (userGroupData.Count != 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (string groupId in userGroupData[0].Split(","))
                                        {
                                            //Some Code Here...
                                            if (groupIdValid)
                                            {
                                                //Some Code Here...
                                                if (signedInUserGroupOwner)
                                                {
                                                    //Some Code Here...
                                                    if (!invitedUserGroupMember)
                                                    {
                                                        //Some Code Here...
                                                        if (addInvitedUserToGroupStatus)
                                                        {
                                                            //Some Code Here...
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    #endregion
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }

            //Some Code Here...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Some Code Here...
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Please select the file first to upload.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have gone through various online sources, aware of the **4 min.** TCP Keep-alive limit {**SOURCE:** [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676086/9275701}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676086/9275701%7D) and also tried increasing the execution time limit in **Web.Config** file as shown below but **NO luck**.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="99999" />
</system.web>
```

Can any one please please please **help** here what I can do for this?

**NOTE:** The bulk requests is being sent via CSV and processing time can take up to hours. Currently, When I try locally for 50 users it takes approx. 12 mins. to process the entire user records.

Answer (score 0):

- We need to add the `maxRequestLength` in `web.config` file
- The parameter `maxRequestLength`  indicates maximum file uploading size supported by the ASP. Net Application
  To increase the execution time limit in `web.config` add the below settings

```cs
 <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
 </system.web>
```

Also, we need to add the `maxAllowedContentLength` under  `system.webServer` tag.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The Compilation debug has to be set to`false`
***My web.config***
[image]

Comment: Tried the solution but it didn't resolved the issue and still throws the same Request Timeout Error. :(